# "Pipeline-as-Code" solution for TFS

Tags: tfs, build

Without switching over to Jenkins to do builds, is there (or will there be in the foreseeable future) a pipeline as code solution for TFS build?

EDIT: For clarity and future reference, I'm looking for a declarative method of defining a build, like appveyor or Travis or Jenkins do. Checkout the answer for the uservoice suggestion for this functionality.

Comment: Can you explain? Are you looking for an Import/Export capability, API to manipulate pipelines or a declarative language to build one?

Comment: Please explain what you want to do? If you don't want to use Jenkins to build, TFS already has the build features. Start to learn TFS build from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/overview.

Comment: I want a file as a part of my code repository that defines the build steps that TFS uses to build the source. Like this: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/ Yes, Giulio, a declaritive language. I know there are XAML builds as a legacy holdover, but those do not go into souce control with the codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any way to achieve this feature for now but we have already started working on this. Refer to this feature request on VSTS User Voice site for details: [provide a way to version-control build definitions](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037625-provide-a-way-to-version-control-build-definitions).